# Principal.Identity.Name in Task ran from Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, task-parallel-library, ninject, task

In a controller action I'm running

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
        myService.ExecuteMethod( someArgs );
    } );
}
```

The service will call other class methods that call others, and somewhere down the line, an `IPrincipal` is injected into the constructor of a class.

The `IPrincipal` is created by doing `HttpContext.Current.User`.

Since the code is in a `Task`, it runs on a different thread, and the action has returned so `HttpContext.Current` is `null`.

If I try doing `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, it exists, but is set to something other than what the `HttpContext.Current.User` was. Also, if I try accessing `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`, I get an `ObjectDisposedException` thrown.

I'm using Ninject for my IoC container. The `IPrincipal` binding looks like this

```
Bind<IPrincipal>().ToMethod( x => HttpContext.Current.User );
```

Is there a way to get the correct or even a usable `IPrincipal` in the code ran from a `Task` in a controller action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `HttpContext.Current.User` is basically something like a temporary `ThreadLocal`. As such, you'll need to retrieve it's value before starting a task which is run in a different thread. There's no way to find out which thread has executed `Task.Factory.StartNew` and retrieve it's `ThreadLocal` values.
Consider, that once you do `Task.Factory.StartNew` the webrequest may end even before the task has actually started.
So what you need to do is something along the lines of:

```
IPrincipal principal = HttpContext.Current.User;

Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
{
    myService.ExecuteMethod(principal);
} );
```

Now however if `IPrincipal` is (ctor-)injected into `myService` **and** `myService` is instantiated per request (`.InTransientScope()`, `.InRequestScope()`) your current binding would work, since the controller is instanciated for each request (also see [lifecycle of an asp.net mvc5 application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application)).

The problem would only arise when injecting `Lazy<IPrincipal>` or when doing `IResolutionRoot.Get<IPrincipal>` (this includes usage of ninject.extensions.factory, like `Func<IPrincipal>`!), because at that point `HttpContext.Current.User` may not be valid any more.

I suggest that if you want an answer more precise and more to the point, you need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That is what I was thinking. I thought maybe there was something I was missing that I could use. Oh well. I'm just passing it into the method call now instead.